# How to take the first element of each element of a RDD[Double,Double] and create a diagonal matrix with it?

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark, rdd

I'm working on Spark in Scala and I want to transform

```
 Array[(Double, Double)] = Array((0.9398785848878621,1.0), (0.25788885483788343,1.0), (0.6093264774118677,1.0), (0.19736451516248585,0.0), (0.9952925254744414,1.0), (0.6920511147023924,0.0...
```

into something like

```
 Array[Double]=Array(0.9398785848878621, 0.25788885483788343, 0.6093264774118677, 0.19736451516248585, 0.9952925254744414 , 0.6920511147023924 ...
```

How can I do it?
Then how can I use this Array[Double] to create a diagonal matrix ?

Comment: What is wrong with `rdd_1.map( x => x(0) )`

Comment: I got this :
    
     scala> predictionAndLabels.map( x => x(0) )
     <console>:49: error: (Double, Double) does not take parameters
              predictionAndLabels.map( x => x(0) )
                                             ^

Comment: This isn't really a Spark question -- this is a pure Scala question.

Comment: yes, with the use of RDD

Comment: What do you mean by "diagonal matrix"? What data structure/collection do you want to end up with? Array[Array[Double]]? something else?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseMatrix$ - See the spdiag method.

Comment: I want to end up with something I can multiply at each side to a matrix.

Comment: How to know what to import for spdiag ?

Comment: But Scala doesn't have a  matrix type. Spark does, do you mean a Spark Matrix. And for the import, I'm guessing org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseMatrix.

Comment: Yes, I mean Spark Matrix, I didn't know that before

Answer (score 2):

Just take the first part of your tuple :

```
val a = Array((0.9398785848878621,1.0), (0.25788885483788343,1.0))
val result = a.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}

    val a = Array((0.9398785848878621,1.0), (0.25788885483788343,1.0), ...)
    val res1 = a.map(_._1)

    val entries = New Array[Double](res1.length)
    for (i <- 0 to res1.length - 1){
        entries(i) = MatrixEntry(i,i,res1(i))
    }

    val mat = CoordinateMatrix(sc.parallelize(res1))
```